# Junit before class ( non static )

Tags: java, junit

Are there any best practices to get Junit execute a function once in a test file , and it should also not be static.

like `@BeforeClass` on non static function?

Here is an ugly solution :

```
@Before void init(){
    if (init.get() == false){
        init.set(true);
        // do once block
    }
}
```

well this is something i dont want to do , and i am looking for an integrated junit solution.

Comment: Well , i have a quite a big hierarchy of test files , and base test files , i need the possibility to override this action in the child test classes.

Comment: i had the same problem in which only the first of many parametrized tests should perform a login.

Comment: Note that the "ugly" solution, the one that works with plain JUnit, don't take tearing tests down into account.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't want to set up static initializers for one time initialization and are not particular about using JUnit, take a look at TestNG. TestNG supports non-static, one-time initialization with a variety of configuration options, all using annotations.

In TestNG, this would be equivalent to:

```
@org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass
public void setUpOnce() {
   // One time initialization.
}
```

For teardown,

```
@org.testng.annotations.AfterClass
public void tearDownOnce() {
   // One time tear down.
}
```

For the TestNG equivalent of JUnit 4's `@Before` and `@After`, you can use `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` respectively.

Answer (score 44):

A simple if statement seems to work pretty well too:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-context.xml"})
public class myTest {

    public static boolean dbInit = false;

    @Autowired
    DbUtils dbUtils;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){

        if(!dbInit){

            dbUtils.dropTables();
            dbUtils.createTables();
            dbInit = true;

        }
    }

 ...
```

Comment: Nice and simple! But can't see a way of simply adapting this to make a non-static `@AfterClass` equivalent that tears down after all the tests have run?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087959/junit-run-set-up-method-once/31117171#31117171) for an update to this method that should work for test classes that use inheritance.

Answer (score 37):

To use an empty constructor is the easiest solution. You can still override the constructor in the extended class.

But it's not optimal with all the inheritance. That's why JUnit 4 uses annotations instead.

Another option is to create a helper method in a factory/util class and let that method do the work.

If you're using Spring, you should consider using the `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation.
Something like this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({CustomTestExecutionListener.class, 
     DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration("test-config.xml")
public class DemoTest {
```

Spring's `AbstractTestExecutionListener` contains for example this empty method that you can override:

```
public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    /* no-op */
}
```

**NOTE:** DO NOT overlook/miss `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener` while adding custom `TestExecutionListeners`. If you do, all the autowires will be `null`.

Comment: +1 This technique solved my problem when wanting to use DbUnit and only load dataset once per class

Comment: +1 This is perfect... for people who are not tied to an ancient version of Spring. :(

Comment: Will this `beforeTestClass()` called before or after context initialized?

Comment: @Dims **after** context initialized

Answer (score 8):

Easily use `@BeforeAllMethods`/`@AfterAllMethods` annotations to run a method inside the instance context (non-static), where all injected values will be available.

There is a special testing library for this:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bitbucket.radistao.test/before-after-spring-test-runner/0.1.0

https://bitbucket.org/radistao/before-after-spring-test-runner/

The only limitation: works only for *Spring* testing.

(I'm the developer of this testing library)

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried but maybe you can create a no-argument constructor and call you function from there?

Comment: This would work , the problem is that I need the possibility to override this action in the classes that extend this base test class

Comment: @Roman: oh, now I see. Add this to your post, this comment makes things much clearer.

Comment: Constructor will be called as many times the test cases are there. For each test method, new Test class object will be created. So, using constructor is not a solution here

Comment: Also this wont work with dependency injection that relies on the object already constructed.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: Please see the comment by Cherry for why the suggestion below is flawed.** (Am keeping the answer on here rather than deleting as the comment may provide useful information to others as to why this **doesn't** work.)

---

<strike>Another option worth considering if using dependency injection (e.g. Spring) is [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html). This will guarantee dependency injection is complete, which wouldn't be the case in a constructor:</strike>

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // One-time initialization...
}
```

Comment: Very **bad** solution in case of Junit tests. Junit creates test  class instance everytime when it runs a test method. So if there 6 test methods in class, a class constructor, `@Before` and `@After` methods will be called 6 times! So in this context `@PostConstruct` behaves like `@Before` annotation. You can simply test it: just put 2 test methods in test class, add `@PostConstruct public void init() {System.out.println("started");}` and see in logs how many time it is printed.

Comment: For info I just came across the [JUnit documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) that confirms what's described in the comment above about JUnit creating an instance for each `@Test` run: *"To run the method, JUnit first constructs a fresh instance of the class then invokes the annotated method."*

Answer (score 0):

[The article](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2012/09/enhancing-spring-test-framework-with.html) discuss 2 very nice solutions for this problem:

1. "clean" junit with custom Runner (using interface but you could extend it with a custom annotation e.g. @BeforeInstance)
2. Spring execution listeners as mentioned by Espen before.

Answer (score -5):

Just use `@BeforeClass`:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
}
```

It doesn't make sense for `init` to be non-static because each test is run in a separate instance. The instance
that `init` is run on would not match the instance of any test.

The only reason that you might want it to be non-static is to override it in subclasses, but you can do this
with static methods too. Just use the same name, and only the subclass `init` method will be called.

Comment: This whole question is about the possibility to do it in a non-static way, which is needed if you need some instance-variables on the class.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Yes, and I'm saying the question is an XY problem. The op said the problem was overriding the behavior in child classes. If the example needed instance variables, then I might suggest something else.

Comment: See this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825615/junit-before-class-non-static/27730780?noredirect=1#comment2866266_2825615

Comment: @SimonForsberg That's the comment I was talking about. What about it?