# Junit - run set up method once

Tags: java, junit

I set up a class with a couple of tests and rather than using `@Before` I would like to have a setup method that executes only once before all tests. Is that possible with Junit 4.8?

Comment: Have a look at RunListener: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14773170/548473

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Although I agree with @assylias that using `@BeforeClass` is a classic solution it is not always convenient. The method annotated with `@BeforeClass` must be static. It is very inconvenient for some tests that need instance of test case. For example Spring based tests that use `@Autowired` to work with services defined in spring context.

In this case I personally use regular `setUp()` method annotated with `@Before` annotation and manage my custom `static`(!)  `boolean` flag:

```
private static boolean setUpIsDone = false;
.....
@Before
public void setUp() {
    if (setUpIsDone) {
        return;
    }
    // do the setup
    setUpIsDone = true;
}
```

Comment: Adding to Kenny Cason's comment as to why it must be static. It must be static because JUnit instantiates a new instance of the test class for each @Test method. The instance variable will be reset to it's default value (false) for each instance if it's not static. See for more info: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/JunitNewInstance.html

Comment: This works except in the case where the `setUp()` method is in a superclass - have posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087959#31117171) below attempting to resolve this.

Comment: I hesitate to say this to someone with an 84k rep, but BeforeClass doesn't in fact answer the question: BeforeClass is run at the beginning of every test class.  But the OP asked for one which runs "only once before all tests".  Your proposed solution could do this, but you'd have to make all your test classes extend a "CommonTest" class...

Comment: @mikerodent, IMHO OP asked about all tests within his test case, not all tests overall. So, your comment is less relevant. BTW, do not worry to say anything to any person even if his reputation is high. At least this is what I do :). And my reputation was significantly lower at Aug 2012 when I answered the question.

Comment: Doesn't work for my case, variables initialized in the setup are reseted after each test, so it's pointless to init only once.

Comment: This should NOT be an accepted answer, no answer I can see here can. Note that JUnit execution engines can use multiple runners (separate JVMs) so static "setUpIsDone" flag won't work guarantee singular execution.

Answer (score 97):

You can use [the `BeforeClass` annotation](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.8/):

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    //executed only once, before the first test
}
```

Comment: I cannot use this, I have e few setup methods that are based on non-static components such as getClass()

Comment: @Bober02 BeforeClass needs to be static indeed. If you can't use that, the other answer provides a workaround.

Comment: Sure you cannot use `TheClassYouWant.class` instead of your getClass() call? This is actual Java: `String.class.getName()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574513/junit-run-setup-only-once-for-a-large-number-of-test-classes/22186630#22186630

Comment: This looks promising.. I had the same problem as @Bober02 but will keep this mind for next time..

Comment: I hesitate to say this to someone with a 184k rep (!), but BeforeClass doesn't in fact answer the question: BeforeClass is run at the beginning of every test class.  But the OP asked for one which runs "only once before all tests".

Comment: @mikerodent I understood the question as "all tests in the class" - but you're right it may not be what the OP wanted.

Comment: Yep, sorry, my silliness in not reading the question properly.

Answer (score 32):

JUnit 5 now has a @BeforeAll annotation:

> Denotes that the annotated method should be executed before all @Test
>   methods in the current class or class hierarchy; analogous to JUnit
>   4’s @BeforeClass. Such methods must be static.

The lifecycle annotations of JUnit 5 seem to have finally gotten it right!  You can guess which annotations available without even looking (e.g. @BeforeEach @AfterAll)

Comment: It has the same problem was `@BeforeClass`, it needs to be `static`. IMO @AlexR's solution is nicer.

Comment: @zengr tend to agree with you: as I have said to AlexR, his solution requires all the test classes to subclass from a CommonTest class if it is only to run once.  But it is simple as simple can be, and IMHO you probably shouldn't use a "fancy" framework-supplied solution when a simple mechanism is available from the language.  Unless there's a good reason of course.  Also, using a simple thing like his, with a good "does what it says on the tin" type name, helps with readability.

Comment: Having said this, again IMHO, there seems much more justification for having an "AfterAll" annotation: it would be very difficult and contrived to devise a mechanism for detecting when all tests were done.  Conversely, of course, purists are probably going to say you should never have to do a "final cleanup", i.e. that each "tearDown" should leave all resources in a pristine state... and they're probably right!

Comment: Does this work with Maven where there are multiple modules, each with their tests?

Comment: @mike rodent, in my case setting up and tearing down test files in the filesystem before/after each test seems to be leading to deadlocks on the files.  For now, I've arrived independently at AlexR's solution to setting up once.  I have two static flags, alreadySetup and dirty.  setup() calls cleanup() if a dirty state is detected initially, or if a setup failure leads to a dirty state.  To clean up after running tests, I run them again.  Messy, not ideal at all, not in our build process.  Still looking for a better way (jUnit 4.12).

Comment: I think you still have to use this information to get the desired effect. "If you would prefer that JUnit Jupiter execute all test methods on the same test instance, simply annotate your test class with @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS). When using this mode, a new test instance will be created once per test class. Thus, if your test methods rely on state stored in instance variables, you may need to reset that state in (at)BeforeEach or (at)AfterEach methods."

Answer (score 10):

When `setUp()` is in a superclass of the test class (e.g. `AbstractTestBase` below), the accepted answer can be modified as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractTestBase {
    private static Class<? extends AbstractTestBase> testClass;
    .....
    public void setUp() {
        if (this.getClass().equals(testClass)) {
            return;
        }

        // do the setup - once per concrete test class
        .....
        testClass = this.getClass();
    }
}
```

This should work for a single non-static `setUp()` method but I'm unable to produce an equivalent for `tearDown()` without straying into a world of complex reflection... Bounty points to anyone who can!

Answer (score 7):

JUnit 5 @BeforeAll can be non static provided the lifecycle of the test class is per class, i.e., annotate the test class with a `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` and you are good to go

Answer (score 4):

***Edit:***
I just found out while debugging that the class is instantiated before every test too.
I guess the @BeforeClass annotation is the best here.

You can set up on the constructor too, the test class **is** a class after all.
I'm not sure if it's a bad practice because almost all other methods are annotated, but it works. You could create a constructor like that:

```
public UT () {
    // initialize once here
}
@Test
// Some test here...
```

The ctor will be called before the tests because they are not static.

Answer (score 2):

Use Spring's @PostConstruct method to do all initialization work and this method runs before any of the @Test is executed

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46274919/907576 :

with `@BeforeAllMethods`/`@AfterAllMethods` annotation you could execute any method in Test class in an instance context, where all injected values are available.

Comment: Relies on a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

My dirty solution is:

```
public class TestCaseExtended extends TestCase {

    private boolean isInitialized = false;
    private int serId;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        if(!isInitialized) {
            loadSaveNewSerId();
            emptyTestResultsDirectory();
            isInitialized = true;
        }
    }

   ...

}
```

I use it as a base base to all my testCases.

Comment: public class TestCaseExtended extends TestCase {
    private static boolean isInitialized = false;
    private static TestCaseExtended caseExtended;
    private int serId;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        if (!isInitialized) {
            caseExtended = new TestCaseExtended();
            caseExtended.loadSaveNewSerId();
            caseExtended.emptyTestResultsDirectory();
            isInitialized = true;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to force a declaration of a variable that is set and checked on each subtest, then adding this to a SuperTest could do:

```
public abstract class SuperTest {

    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Class, Boolean> INITIALIZED = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    protected final boolean initialized() {
        final boolean[] absent = {false};
        INITIALIZED.computeIfAbsent(this.getClass(), (klass)-> {
            return absent[0] = true;
        });
        return !absent[0];
    }
}



public class SubTest extends SuperTest {
    @Before
    public void before() {
        if ( super.initialized() ) return;

         ... magic ... 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

Add to your **Base** abstract class (I mean abstract class where you initialize your driver in *setUpDriver()* method) this part of code:

```
private static boolean started = false;
static{
    if (!started) {
        started = true;
        try {
            setUpDriver();  //method where you initialize your driver
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

And now, if your test classes will extends from **Base** abstract class -> *setUpDriver()* method will be executed before first @Test only **ONE** time per run.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting for some time this is my solution. I needed this for spring boot test. I tried using @PostConstruct, unfortunately it is executed for every test.

```
public class TestClass {
    private static TestClass testClass = null;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        if (testClass == null) {
            // set up once
            ...
            testClass = this;
        }
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanUpAfterAll() {
        testClass.cleanUpAfterAllTests();
    }
    private void cleanUpAfterAllTests() {
        // final cleanup after all tests
        ...
    }
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // test 1
        ...
    }
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        // test 2
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one alternative suggestion:

What I do to get this working is
Create a method named _warmup or just _
Annotate the test class with @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)

This is applicable only if you run all tests in the class

It has a downside of having additional test included, which will also run one additional @Before and @After
It is usually advised for your test methods to be order independent, this breaks that rule, but why someone would like tests ordered randomly in the reports I have no clue so NAME_ASCENDING is what I always use

But the upsides to this is simple setup with minimal code and without the need to extend classes/runners etc...
Test run lengths are more accurate since all setup time is reported on method _warmup

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `@BeforeClass` is that it fires before the constructor.
So if you rely on an `@Autowired` constructor to provide data, it simply will not work: wrong execution order.

Similarly `@PostConstruct` fires after the constructor has been called. And the constructor fires with every `@Test`, therefore your setup function will fire with every test, if you use this.
This has the exact same effect as calling a function from the constructor.

The only solution, I found that works, is to use a flag to indicate if the `setUp()` method has already been executed. While its not ideal, it will drastically reduce the amount of processing before each test.

```
private static boolean initialized = false;    

@Autowired
public CacheTest( MyBean myBean ){

    this.myBean = myBean;
}


@PostConstruct
public static void setUp(){

    if( initialized ) { return };

    initialized = true;
    
    //do suff with myBean
}
```