# Run JUnit setup and teardown exactly once for any test(s) run

Tags: java, junit, java-7, junit4

Before every JUnit test I run certain things need to be set up. Some properties need to be loaded, a database connection needs to be made, a separate J2SE application needs to be started, etc. When every single test has finished the database connection can be killed and J2SE application shut down.

I can accomplish this by using @BeforeClass and @AfterClass annotations in a test suite, but that limits me to only being able to run tests inside the suite. If I want to run an individual test outside of a suite it won't run the suite setup and teardown methods. Likewise, if I want to run an individual test method (through an IDE) it won't run the setup and teardown from the suite.

Is there a way to setup JUnit tests so that, no matter how they're run, through a suite, or a test case, or an individual method, they always run a setup method **only** once before running anything, and a teardown **only** once after every test has been executed? Having all of the test cases extend an abstract class with a static initializer solves the setup problem, but not teardown.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087959/junit-run-set-up-method-once

Comment: @mre That solution only works for the initial setup. If I have a tearDown method that only runs with tearDownIsDone is false it will run once the first class is finished, not once **every** class is finished. I need a solution that works for both setup and tearDown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I needed using two separate methods. I'd prefer if just one method worked, but this will do...

I have a custom RunListener class that implements testRunFinished:

```
public class MyRunListener extends RunListener
{
    @Override
    public void testRunFinished(Result result) throws Exception
    {
        //Do whatever teardown needs to be done
    }
}
```

I then have a custom BlockJUnit4ClassRunner class with the following run() method:

```
private static boolean listenerAdded = false;
@Override 
public void run(RunNotifier notifier)
{
    //listenerAdded required or else the listener will be added once for every test case, and testRunFinished will be run multiple times
    if(!listenerAdded)
    {
        listenerAdded = true;
        notifier.addListener(new MyRunListener());
    }
    super.run(notifier);
}
```

An abstract test case class uses the annotation:

```
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)
```

I was hoping that I could also implement testRunStarted in MyRunListener but it didn't work. Apparently adding the listener like this in MyRunner, the listener isn't added until **after** the testRunStarted method would have been run, so it isn't being executed. The workaround for this is, as mentioned in the original question, to use a static initilizer in AbstractTestCase:

```
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)
public class AbstractTestCase
{
    private static boolean setupDone = false;
    static
    {
        if(!setupDone)
        {
            setupDone = true;
            //Do whatever setup needs to be done
        }
    }
...
```

If anyone knows of a way to add MyRunListener that will allow the use of testRunStarted that would be nice, but in the meantime this works.