# android junit setup for all classes

Tags: android, testing, junit, tdd

I wanna setup all stuff for all my tests. They are in different classes. There is @BeforeClass, but with it, my setup will be executed in every class. Can I configure it for the whole project?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify that a bit more? Are you saying you want to run some setup code before the entire suite of tests is executed?

Comment: exactly @MichaelDodd!

Comment: @qbait https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087959/junit-run-set-up-method-once