# How to execute a piece of code once before all test classes start?

Tags: java, spring, junit4

How can I execute a method once before all tests in all classes start?

I have a program that needs a system property to be set before any test start. Is there any way to do that?

Note: `@BeforeClass` or `@Before` are used just for the same test class. In my case, I'm looking for a way to execute a method before all test classes start.

Comment: [`BeforeClass`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Junit - run set up method once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087959/junit-run-set-up-method-once)

Answer (score 1):

if you need to run that method before the start of all test you should use the annotation `@BeforeClass` or if you need to execute the same method every time you will execute a test method of that class you must use `@Before`

f.e

```
@Before
public void executedBeforeEach() {
   //this method will execute before every single test
}

@Test
public void EmptyCollection() {
  assertTrue(testList.isEmpty());     
}
```

Comment: For your information, in the context of your answer, `@BeforeClass` is known as an **_annotation_** and not a _tag_.

Answer (score 1):

To setup precondition to your test cases you can use something like this -

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    // Set up you preconditions here
    // This piece of code will be executed before any of the test case execute 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can make use of a Test Suite.

The test suite

```java
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ TestClass.class, Test2Class.class, })
public class TestSuite {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {

        // the setup
    }
}
```

and, the test classes

```java
public class Test2Class {

    @Test
    public void test2() {

        // some test
    }
}
```

```java
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        // some test
    }
}
```

#### Or, you can have a base class which handles the setup

```java
public class TestBase {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {

        // setup
    }
}
```

and, then the test classes can extend the base class

```java
public class TestClass extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        // some test
    }
}
```

```java
public class Test2Class extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        // some test
    }
}
```

However, this will call the `setup` method in `TestBase` for all its subclasses everytime each of them executes.