# Why is a class reloaded with a junit test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I've noticed the behavior within my unit tests that final fields are reloaded, actually the whole class does so (hashcode of it changes)

Example:

```
class SomeTest {


    private final String aRandomString  = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10);

    @Test
    void a() {
    }

    @Test
    void b() {
    }
}
```

`aRandomString` changes for method a and b.

**Why** is that *and* is there a way to prevent this?
(my question is more theoretical right now without a particular use case atm)

My POM has only these test dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: This might answer the first question at least: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/JunitNewInstance.html and a couple of links regarding your second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087959/junit-run-set-up-method-once, https://www.guru99.com/junit-test-framework.html, https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations, https://www.baeldung.com/junit-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-beforeall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the default TestInstance lifecycle is PER_METHOD.

that mean is your every test method are have each Instace.

so fast answer is add TestInstance annotation.

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class yourTest {
    ...
}
```

but this solution have to be careful not to violate FIRST unit testing principles.