# How to require that JUnit tests implement a @BeforeClass/@AfterClass "abstract method"?

Tags: java, junit, testng

As a heavy TestNG user, this is not a problem, since `@{Before,After}Class` methods are not `static`...

But in JUnit, they are.

And this is quite a problem for what I am currently doing.

I am writing assertions for java.nio.file.Path for [assertj](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core), which uses JUnit 4.x for tests. Some assertions require that I initialize a `FileSystem` (a [memoryfs](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem) to be precise) to test them; such a filesystem should, ideally, be initialized at the test class level and not per test. And depending on the test class, I need to initialize the contents of that filesystem differently.

Right now however, I use `@Before`/`@After` since I don't know better...

Again, with TestNG, not a problem, since `@{Before,After}Class` are not static. So, how do you do this with JUnit?
.

Comment: Similar issue is over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825615/junit-before-class-non-static) and accepted answer seems recommendation to use testng or a hack with @RunWith(MyClass.class) :(

Comment: @almasshaikh eh, so you are a TestNG user too ;) Anyway, here I don't have a choice... I see that an answer suggests a constructor, I may go with that. I just wondered whether there would be a builtin mechanism. When you use TestNG, using JUnit _really_ feels like a step backwards :/

Comment: Downvoter please explain

Comment: @fge The question is quite unclear, and seems to jump to premature conclusions (template method approach). As always, a concrete code example (e.g. how you would write this test in TestNG) would help.

Comment: What is your intention? Is it that you want to require that subclass impls take action before/after class?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser _unclear_? I believe that I have expressed my need pretty well myself

Comment: @Bohemian yes, exactly

Comment: @fge You expressed a (flawed) solution rather than the problem, and your words leave a lot of guesswork. Also the question has been asked before. Anyway, a class rule is likely the best solution.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser what flawed solution? The need was pretty well explained: I need a `FileSystem` for some test classes and I need it to be initialized only once per test class. What is not clear in that?

Comment: Read the title and (most of) the body of your question. It's all about implementation details of a solution you had in mind ("@BeforeClass/@AfterClass abstract method", "methods are not static", etc.), rather than explaining the real problem. Also you didn't explain why the most direct solution (having a `@BeforeClass` in each test class, without a common base class) isn't good enough in your case. (You didn't even mention that there is a base class; again this has to be inferred from the context.) Of course readers can make educated guesses on all these things, but they shouldn't have to.

Comment: (Presenting a model TestNG solution that you want to "recreate" in JUnit would have answered most of these questions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a rule class for your initialization:

```
public class Resource extends ExternalResource {
    protected void before() {
        // ...
    }

    protected void after() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and then reference it in each test:

```
@ClassRule public static Resource resource = new Resource();
```

Any per-test customisation can be done by making resource an anonymous inner class and
overriding methods, or passing parameters to its constructor.

If you have a common base class, you can put `resource` in there, and then only declare it in subclasses that need to customize it. In junit, class rules in subclasses will override class rules in a parent class with the same name.

Comment: Hmm, so, let's say that I have a `FileSystem` to create; I'd create it in the constructor, set it up in `before()` and close it in `after()`, is that it? Then how do I access it? Do I make a getter on the instance?

Comment: @fge Yes, save an instance in the constructor or the before method, and add a getter.

Comment: OK, it works. Thanks! But frankly, whoever decided that per-class test resources had to be `static` should have been killed at birth.

Comment: It needs to be static, as otherwise a separate rule would be created for each test method.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser coming from a TestNG background, this is a pretty severe limitation ;)

Comment: TestNG reuses the test object for every test method, so class-based setup can be done in a non-static method. JUnit creates a new instance of the test class for every method, so class-based setup needs to involve statics. JUnit creates a new instance of your class for each test to limit the likelihood that one test method could pass/fail depending on whether another test method was called first.