# JUnit @BeforeClass non-static work around for Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, dependency-injection, spring-boot

JUnit's `@BeforeClass` annotation must be declared static if you want it to run once before all the `@Test` methods. However, this cannot be used with dependency injection.

I want to clean up a database that I `@Autowire` with Spring Boot, once before I run my JUnit tests. I cannot `@Autowire` static fields so I need to think of a work around. Any ideas?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just use [`@Before`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Before.html) (instead of [`@BeforeClass`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/BeforeClass.html)) (or Spring's [`@BeforeTransaction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/BeforeTransaction.html) (depending on how you initialize the database)). This annotation must been attached to an nonstatic public method.

Of course:  `@Before` run before EACH test case method (not like `@BeforeClass` that runs only once.) But if you want to run it exactly once, then use an static marker field.

```
private static boolean initialized = false;
...
@Before
public void initializeDB() { 
   if (!initialized) {
       ... //your db initialization
       initialized = true;
   }
}
---
```

Comment: that's what i do when i have to use JUnit. But I prefer to use TestNG which has all annotations available on non-static methods : in your case with TestNG, @BeforeClass would be defined on a non-static methods, and is would be executed once before all the test methods inside that class.

Comment: Is there a workaround for `@AfterClass`? I want to remove all data inserted in the database because I'm using an external database.

Comment: @LunaticJape: my workarround is to use the `@After` Method to pass an instance (`@Autowired` field value) to an static field, and then use this field in the `@AfterClass` Method.

Comment: @LunaticJape see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083647/junit-afterclass-non-static

Answer (score 5):

For **`JUnit5`**:   [Test Execution Order](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.2/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order) and `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`

Kotlin example:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)
class BeforeInstanceTests {

    private var initialized: String = ""
    private val callList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

    @BeforeAll
    fun beforeAllNonStatic() {
        initialized = "initialized"
        assertEquals(0, callList.size)
    }

    @Test
    fun test1() {
        assertEquals("initialized", initialized)
        callList.add("test1")
    }

    @Test
    fun test2() {
        assertEquals("initialized", initialized)
        callList.add("test2")
    }

    @Test
    fun test3() {
        assertEquals("initialized", initialized)
        callList.add("test3")
    }

    @AfterAll
    fun afterAllNonStatic() {
        assertEquals("initialized", initialized)
        assertEquals(3, callList.size)
        assertTrue(callList.contains("test1"))
        assertTrue(callList.contains("test2"))
        assertTrue(callList.contains("test3"))

        callList.clear()
        initialized = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) library - it's designed to perform the actions you're describing. It can create & tear down database instances and provides you with simple ways to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Though accepted answer is clever, seems hacky. Have you tried using a normal Constructor?

```
public class MyJUnitTest {

    public MyJUnitTest() {
       // code for initializeDB
    }

    // Tests

}
```

Comment: This won't work. JUnit creates a new instance of the testing class for each \@Test. So using the constructor is effectively the same as \@Before, not \@BeforeClass

Answer (score -2):

Try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46274919/907576 :

with `@BeforeAllMethods`/`@AfterAllMethods` annotations you could execute any method in Test class in an instance context, where all injected values are available.

Comment: This doesn't work because these annotations don't exist in a spring boot application. The question clearly says Spring boot application! Don't give advice that doesn't work.

Comment: In the mentioned solution there are references to the dependencies with the annotations. Because stackoverflow doesn't allow duplicate answers i just mentioned the references to another more descriptive answer.