# Spring integration/unit tests: clean up database after tests in JUnit

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jpa, junit

I'm developing a backend application in SpringBoot + JPA. I have a bunch of unit tests and integration tests, and the latter use the database. I'd like to do setup before all the tests and a teardown afterward.

**Setup**: I do this in `@Before` and I use boolean `setUpIsDone` to make sure it is done **once**. Works fine.

**Teardown** - here I have a problem:

- I can't use `@AfterClass` because it's static. In JPA MyRepository
  class is just an interface annotated with @Autowired. So there is no
  instance of repository that I can use.
- I can't use `@After` because it would try to clean the test data after every test. I can't use any boolean flag like in case of `@Before` - how would I determine which test is the last one?
- Spring rollback mechanism has some flaws because it doesn't write to the database physically so sometimes tests are passing but don't when rollback is disabled

For now there are a few solutions coming to my mind, but none is satysfiyng:

1. Setup and cleanup along with every test (too time consuming)
2. Pick
   other test framework than JUnit (I've read that only JUnit forces
   static `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`)

Any help?

Comment: If using JPA you can signal the transaction manager to automatically rollback every transaction

Comment: Please look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4

Comment: sure, but see the third bullet point

Comment: Also consider TestNG http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669576/order-of-execution-of-tests-in-testng

Comment: @kiedysktos sorry, I didn't notice

Comment: @kiedysktos check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825615/junit-before-class-non-static